# WebAPI AND Odata V4 issue: ComplexType containing Entities

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I am getting following error while adding relationship inside the complex type. How can I fix this issue. I binged and read that it was issue with OData V3 but not in OData V4.

The complex type 'Microsoft.OneIM.ActiveIncident.Contracts.IncidentImpact' refers to the entity type 'Microsoft.OneIM.ActiveIncident.Contracts.ImpactedService' through the property 'ImpactedServices'.

at System.Web.OData.Builder.ODataConventionModelBuilder.MapComplexType(ComplexTypeConfiguration complexType)
   at System.Web.OData.Builder.ODataConventionModelBuilder.MapType(StructuralTypeConfiguration edmType)
   at System.Web.OData.Builder.ODataConventionModelBuilder.AddComplexType(Type type)
   at System.Web.OData.Builder.ODataConventionModelBuilder.ReconfigureEntityTypesAsComplexType(EntityTypeConfiguration[] misconfiguredEntityTypes)
   at System.Web.OData.Builder.ODataConventionModelBuilder.RediscoverComplexTypes()
   at System.Web.OData.Builder.ODataConventionModelBuilder.GetEdmModel()
   at Microsoft.OneIM.ActiveIncident.Service.ModelBuilder.BuildIncidentModels() in c:\OneIM\EngSys\OneIM\ActiveIncident\src\Product\Service\Models\ModelBuilder.cs:line 42
   at Microsoft.OneIM.ActiveIncident.Service.WebApiConfig.Register(HttpConfiguration config) in c:\OneIM\EngSys\OneIM\ActiveIncident\src\Product\Service\App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs:line 22
   at Microsoft.OneIM.ActiveIncident.ServiceHost.ApiStartup.Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder) in c:\OneIM\EngSys\OneIM\ActiveIncident\src\Product\ServiceHost\ApiStartup.cs:line 27

My model looks as below

```
    public class Incident
    {
            public IncidentImpact Impact { get; set; }
    }

[ComplexType]
public class IncidentImpact
{

    public bool IsCustomerImpacting { get; set; }

    public string SupportTicketId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ImpactedService> ImpactedServices { get; set; }
}


public class ImpactedService
{

     public long Id { get; set; }


      public long IncidentId { get; set; }

    public Incident Incident { get; set; }

    public long ServiceId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although OData protocol V4 support complex type contains entity as navigation property, both of OData Lib and WebAPI OData do not implementation this feature now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a key property by [key] attribute or in the model builder as

```
builder.EntitySet<Type>("Types").EntityType.HasKey(t => t.KeyProperty);
```

Hope it helps.